# Call the same function twice and second one doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sharepoint-2013

All,
I have an interesting one here probably just something I am doing wrong so I could use your help.

I have a function...

```
    function updateStatusNStage(status, stage) {
    var dfdStatusUpdate = new $.Deferred(function() {
        var reqList = modCommon.SharePointContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('RequestDetails'),
            uListItem = reqList.getItemById(ProjectContext.ItemID);

        uListItem.set_item('Stage', stage);
        uListItem.set_item('Status', status);

        uListItem.update();
        modCommon.SharePointContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySNSWriteSucceeded, onQuerySNSWriteFailed);

        function onQuerySNSWriteSucceeded() {
            modCommon.ShowMessage('Stage updated on ' + ProjectContext.ItemID + ' to status of ' + status + ' and stage of ' + stage);
        }

        function onQuerySNSWriteFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Stage Update Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    });
    return dfdStatusUpdate.promise();
}
```

when I execute the following only the first one works.  It seems to me that the promise has already been fulfilled on the first call so How would I do this?

```
    function stageCompleteCheck(stage) {
    var dfd = gheaSPDataAccess.GetDataFromSP("ReviewerAssignment",
            "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='RequestID' /><Value  Type='Number'>" +
            modARBRequest.ProjectContext.ItemID + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Stage' /><Value  Type='Text'>" +
            stage + "</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='RequestID' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='ReviewerEmail' /><FieldRef Name='CategoryID' /><FieldRef Name='Comments' /><FieldRef Name='Result' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Modified' /><FieldRef Name='Stage' /></ViewFields></View>");

    dfd.done(function (reviewsSubmitted) {
        if (modCommon.IsRealValue(reviewsSubmitted)) {
            var reviewersAssignedCnt = $.grep(reviewsSubmitted, function (obj) {
                return obj.Result !== 'NoResult';
            });

            if (reviewsSubmitted.length >= reviewersAssignedCnt.length) {
                // all reviews are in
                if (stage === 'Voting') {
                    var dfdStatusUpdate = modARBRequest.UpdateStatusNStage('Open', 'Voting Completed'); // finalize voting
                    dfdStatusUpdate.done(function() {
                        var updStatus = modARBRequest.UpdateStatusNStage('Open', 'Review Initiated'); // initiate review
                        updStatus.done(function () {
                            alert('hit second update');
                        });
                    });
                }

                if (stage === 'Review') {
                    var dfdStatusUpdate = modARBRequest.UpdateStatusNStage('Open', 'Review Completed');  // finalize review
                    dfdStatusUpdate.done(function() {
                        modARBRequest.UpdateStatusNStage('Closed', 'Final'); // finalize request ?? Do you want a pre-final status to review the decision?
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

the section that is not working is below...

```
if (stage === 'Voting') {
                    var dfdStatusUpdate = modARBRequest.UpdateStatusNStage('Open', 'Voting Completed'); // finalize voting
                    dfdStatusUpdate.done(function() {
                        var updStatus = modARBRequest.UpdateStatusNStage('Open', 'Review Initiated'); // initiate review
                        updStatus.done(function () {
                            alert('hit second update');
                        });
                    });
                }
```

I appreciate any help that you can give me on this one.

Comment: I would throw either a console log or an alert right before the second call- make sure you are getting to that section of code

Comment: The first call does execute and update the list properly.

Comment: I added an alert right after dfdStatusUpdate.done and it never throws it.  Why wouldn't I be getting a done on the first call?

Comment: found it I wasn't adding the .resolve() in the UpdateStatusNStage function.  DOH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it I wasn't adding the .resolve() in the UpdateStatusNStage function.  DOH!

```
    function updateStatusNStage(status, stage) {
    var dfdStatusUpdate = new $.Deferred(function() {
        var reqList = modCommon.SharePointContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('RequestDetails'),
            uListItem = reqList.getItemById(ProjectContext.ItemID);

        uListItem.set_item('Stage', stage);
        uListItem.set_item('Status', status);

        uListItem.update();
        modCommon.SharePointContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySNSWriteSucceeded, onQuerySNSWriteFailed);

        function onQuerySNSWriteSucceeded() {
            modCommon.ShowMessage('Stage updated on ' + ProjectContext.ItemID + ' to status of ' + status + ' and stage of ' + stage);
            dfdStatusUpdate.resolve();
        }

        function onQuerySNSWriteFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Stage Update Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            dfdStatusUpdate.reject();
        }
    });
    return dfdStatusUpdate.promise();
}
```